# How to know my Java Version in Eclips in windows10

Tags: spring-boot

I need know know the java Version to fill the parameter on Spring Initializr and the information under " Spring Boot"3.0.0 (SNAPSHOT)3.0.0 (M5)2.7.5 (SNAPSHOT)2.7.42.6.13 (SNAPSHOT)2.6.12.

Can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: Not to be mean but you might want to learn Java basics before going to Spring Boot. For instance, you can have multiple version of Java in Eclipse and switch between them from one project to another.

Comment: you can use different java version with your Spring framework if you are not sure which java version compatible with your selected Spring framework version you can check gradually by the documentation release or here the compatibility matrix in the github repo documentation https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions

Comment: Run `java -version` in a terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to find the answer by myself.

When we create a java project using Eclipse software using Project -> Package-> Class with(without) "main".

On the first step, Java version(Default) is written. It is a menu, you can choose java version. For me it was java 17 as default. That's where we can find the java version!